# Sencha touch 2.x application layout breaks on Google Chrome update 30

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch-2

I have just updated my Google Chrome installation to the latest version i.e version 30.

The same issue that was reported earlier on the break of application layout while upgrading version 29 appears.

The fix is already implemented in the new release of 2.3 but that works fine on version 29, it still breaks the application on version 30 of chrome.

Is there any solution this one?